# How to show grid lines for rows in TreeTableView

Tags: fxml, javafx-8, java-8

I have the following FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1000.0" stylesheets="@../css/fxmlDemo.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="fxmldemo.controller.MainController">
    <children>
        <TreeTableView fx:id="treeTableView" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1000.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
            <columns>
                <TreeTableColumn fx:id="nameColumn" prefWidth="600.0" text="Name" />
                <TreeTableColumn fx:id="sizeColumn" prefWidth="100.0" text="Size" />
                <TreeTableColumn fx:id="lastModifiedColumn" prefWidth="300.0" text="Modified" />
            </columns>
        </TreeTableView>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And in my fxmlDemo.css file I have tried things like:

```
* { 
  -fx-border-style: solid;
}
```

And

```
tree-table-view { 
  -fx-border-style: solid;
}
```

And

```
tree-item { 
  -fx-border-style: solid;
}
```

The first one puts a border around everything in the FXML, the other two do nothing.

What I want is to show grid lines like an Excel spread sheet.  The code I'm using is very similar to what is seen in [this](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/OpenJDK/TreeTableView+API+Examples#) example, but mine has been modified to actually work :)

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) is a link to the Java FX CSS Reference Guide, but it does not contain information on TreeTableView or its sub-components.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
.tree-table-cell {
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-border-style: solid;
}
```

Go to caspian.css and look at all the table-cell stuff and add 'tree-' in front. They have lots of sub-styles and selectors.

I think '*' doesn't work because the default color is transparent.

Answer (score 23):

Using the following CSS I was able to configure the TreeTableView to look very similar to the TableView.

```
.tree-table-row-cell {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-table-cell-border-color, -fx-control-inner-background;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-padding: 0.0em;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-inner-color;
}
.tree-table-row-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-focus-color, -fx-cell-focus-inner-border, -fx-focus-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
}

.tree-table-row-cell:odd {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-table-cell-border-color, derive(-fx-control-inner-background,-5%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
}

.tree-table-row-cell:selected:odd {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-focus-color, -fx-cell-focus-inner-border, -fx-focus-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
}
```

Remember that you can remove and add a stylesheet to a scene, this will speed up your development time.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I don't understand why they don't have this in by default... they likely just forgot when the did the tree table view.

Comment: For me the color of the odd cells wasn't exactly the same for some reason. I had to use `-fx-background-color: -fx-table-cell-border-color, #F9F9F9;` for the `.tree-table-row-cell:odd`. This seams to be the default color for the odd cells in TableViews.

Comment: use this one : derive(-fx-control-inner-background,-2.5%);
instea of this one : derive(-fx-control-inner-background,-5%); 
it renders a better result

Answer (score 5):

Based on @tunabot 's answer and @Grochni 's comment, I made some fix and I added code to hide the empty rows at the end of the table when it has just a few rows. I share it here for someone who needs it.

```
.tree-table-row-cell {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-table-cell-border-color, -fx-control-inner-background;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
}

.tree-table-row-cell:odd {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-table-cell-border-color, #F9F9F9;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
}

.tree-table-row-cell:selected,
.tree-table-row-cell:selected:odd {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-focus-color, -fx-cell-focus-inner-border, -fx-focus-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
}

.tree-table-row-cell:selected .tree-table-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.tree-table-row-cell:empty {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.tree-table-row-cell:empty .tree-table-cell {
    -fx-border-width: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use modena.css and just want to modify your TreeTableView to look like a TableView try to use following code.
The resulting TreeTableView has/contains:

- Horizontal borders
- Odd rows with different colour
- Same selection behaviour like TableView

CSS file:

```
/* Let TreeTableView rows look like TableView rows  */
 .tree-table-row-cell {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-table-cell-border-color, -fx-background;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
}
/* Let odd rows look different */
.tree-table-row-cell:odd {
    -fx-background: -fx-control-inner-background-alt;
}
/* Selected when control is focused */
.tree-table-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .tree-table-row-cell:selected {
    -fx-background: -fx-selection-bar;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: derive(-fx-selection-bar, 20%);
}
/* Selected when control is not focused */
.tree-table-row-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background: -fx-selection-bar-non-focused;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: derive(-fx-selection-bar-non-focused, 20%);
}
```